# in react i try to send a function as props but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props, mui-datatable

I am trying to make a component that receives props from other components in order to generate a mui table, I send my function as a prop and it works correctly and I even check the network to see that the api works and everything is correct, but my variable is always undefined, I share my code maybe there is something I'm not seeing

```
findAllComplementosFilter(searchText, complementos.page, complementos.rowsPerPage);
```

This is how it sent the props to the component

```
<CustomMuiDataTable
                title={'Complementos de Pago'}
                //data={complementos.data}
                columns={columnsComplemento}
               // customOptions={customOptions}
               fetchData={findAllComplementosFilter}
              />
```

This way I receive it and use it but my newData variable is always undifined

```
const CustomMuiDataTable = ({ title, columns, fetchData })
const petitionData = async () => {
  try{
    const newData = await fetchData(
      data.searchText,
      data.page,
      data.rowsPerPage
    );  
    
    if (newData) {
      const fetchAndSetData = {
        data: newData.content,
        count: newData.totalElements,
        page: newData.pageable ? newData.pageable.pageNumber : null,
        rowsPerPage: newData.pageable ? newData.pageable.pageSize : null,
      };
      setData(fetchAndSetData);
    }
    console.log("data", newData);
  }catch(err){
    console.error("error ",err)
  }
  };
```

try to include the try catch to see if there was a more specific error but it is not marking one

Comment: did you tried  console.log(data.searchText), console.log(data.page) etc?

Comment: Yes,so I realize that my variable is empty

Comment: Which variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)